# Вывод из БД информации по выбранному полю (?)

Tags: php, mysqli

Знак вопроса в названии - я не знаю, как правильно сказать, поэтому он там.
Кривое объяснение в студию -
Есть страница - books, она позволяет вывести из директории картинки, исходя их загруженных в БД. Нужно сделать так, чтобы под каждой картинкой писалось ее название и имя автора. У меня получилось как-то так, но это добро выдает ошибку.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Library\books.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Library\books.php on line 14
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу исправить это и, может, сделать по-другому.

```
 <?php
      $book = "SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE `image`=:image"; // Ваш запрос в БД(поиск записи по id)
      $arr = scandir('book');
      foreach($arr as $v)
      {
      if(stripos($v,'.jpg')) echo '<a href="singlebook.php?image='.$v.'"><img src="book/'.$v."<br>{$book['Name']}</br><br>{$book['Author']}</br>/>'";
       }
 ?>
```

До этого варианта - был другой. Где  выводила данные с помощью цикла, однако он не сопоставлял картинки с данными об этой картинке и в итоге. В общем бред получался. Он выводил сначала все названия/имя автора, что есть в БД, а потом картинки. Под этим всем. То да не то, в общем. (Да, я осознаю, что это был другой запрос и оно не должно было работать как я хотела, но попытка не пытка?)

```
<?php
    $book = "SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE `image`=:image"; // Ваш запрос в БД(поиск записи по id)
    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT * FROM `book`');

        $arr = scandir('book');
        foreach($arr as $v)
            {
            if(stripos($v,'.jpg')) echo '<a href="singlebook.php?image='.$v.'"><img src="book/'.$v.'"/>';
            while ($book = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo 
            "<br>{$book['Name']}</br>" .
            "<br>{$book['Author']}</br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: а как связаны имена файлов и записи в БД?

Comment: splash58, там идет рандомное присвоение имени при добавлении книги:    $apend=$file_name.'_'.date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000).$file_ext;

Comment: Посмотреть историю вопросов любого пользователя - это два клика мышкой. И это всегда полезно, чтобы понять контекст вопроса, особенно если код в нем настолько бессмысленный. Я посмотрел, увидел старый вопрос, в котором есть код, который решает текущую проблему. Рекомендую сделать то же самое